# How to make /users/1 as /users/john-doe in rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using simple scaffold to create users

```
rails g scaffold user fname:string lname:string
```

and when I am creating the user, it is creating it as /users/1, /users/2 etc, I was wondering how to make the users as users/fname-lname ?

is there rails gem available to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is creating a `slug`.

[FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is a gem for doing just that. There's also a Railscast episode on how to use it! [Railscast link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

Answer (score 0):

You can also define, in your **routes.rb** file, something like this:

```
match "users/:fname-:lname/:action", :controller => "users"
```

But when you'll want to access to your ressources you'll have to pass fname and lname parameters.

Comment: Wild route matchers like these are NOT recommended.

Comment: Can you explain me why? I found this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments and they don't warning that it's not recommended.

Comment: Rails guides are there to explain what is possible, it is documentation. Things you should or should not do with what is possible are called best practices, and those aren't listed there. Using wildcard catch-all routes like this are only for when you have no other option, which is not the case here.